# Auto generate numbering list in HTML using CSS

Tags: html, ajax, css

I've been working on TNC for my client. This content will have a lot of `<li></li>` tags. So in order to create the automated numbering, I've been using below code to do the magic.

**CSS :**

```
ol {counter-reset: section;list-style-type: none;padding-left:0}
ol li {counter-increment: section;font-weight:700}
ol li:before {content: counters(section, ".") ". "}
ol li ol {padding-left:15px}
ol li ol li {margin:10px 0}
ul {list-style-type:lower-alpha}
ul li:before {content: ""}
```

**HTML :**

```
<ol>
    <li>
    <span class="underline">Title</span>
        <ol>
            <li>
                Content
            </li>
            <li>
                Content
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="underline">Sub title</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Sub Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Sub Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Sub Content
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Content
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image: Check this image output]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsuuD/)

The problem is the counter seems to be broken after `lower-alpha` style list. I would like to avoid using javascript in this process as this page will be called in other page using [AJAX](http://www.1stwebdesigns.com/blog/development/jquery-terms-and-conditions-link).

Comment: make a fiddle for the same image

Comment: In the example given it looks like there is a missing closing li tag right under </ul>

Comment: Here as requested. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsuuD/)

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/numbered-list-with-subclauses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TRY

```
ol {counter-reset: section;  list-style-type:none;padding-left:0}
ol li:before {counter-increment: section;font-weight:700;content: counters(section, ".") ". "}
ul {counter-reset: section;  list-style-type:lower-alpha}
ul li:before {counter-increment: section; content: ""}
```

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ZsN3H/)

#### update

add `counter-reset` on `ul` for the next (inner) listings

```
 ul {counter-reset: section;list-style-type:lower-alpha}
 ul  li {counter-increment: section;}
 ul li:before {content: ""}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/RsuuD/2/)

Read more on **[Using CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)**

Comment: This data will have 3 level. I will test this out.

Comment: Okay it working. Whats the different here? Mind explaining the code little bit?

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for the details and references.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation atm to upvote. Will do that in future. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Tip : add some class to main `ol` and inner `ol` to differentiate better