# Auto generate numbering list in HTML using CSS #Part II

Tags: html, css

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557582/auto-generate-numbering-list-in-html-using-css), I've been using CSS to create auto generated list numbering for `<li></li>` tags. In another task, I need to create another list that will have title in between of the list as picture shown below.

[image: Example]

Above example can be achieve using below code

**HTML**

```
<ol class="main">
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <li>
        Content
    </li>
    <li>
        Content
    </li>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <li>
        Content
    </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {counter-reset:section}
li {margin:15px 0;text-align:justify}
li:before {counter-increment:section;content:""}
.main {list-style-position:inside;list-style-type:none;padding:0}
.main span {font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline}
.inner {padding:0}
.inner ul {counter-reset:section}
.inner ul > li:before {content:""}
ul {list-style-type:lower-alpha}
```

However, this code doesn't work in some browser like Opera. This is because in HTML 5, `<span></span>` tag can't be nested within element `<ol></ol>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsjY4/) that work in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well, it's against the rules (in all versions of HTML), so the better solution is to find something that is valid HTML first, then check if it works in the browsers.

Comment: Thats I've been looking for answer. Any work around to do that?

Comment: I came up with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/JtFvR/), that works beautifully in Firefox and Opera. Unfortunately, not in IE9 or Chrome. Sorry! Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a pure CSS version](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/RRdqN/2/) which works in Chrome 26 and FF 20 (Haven't tested on other browsers). The change from your earlier question is that you don't need to reset your counter every time.

```
/* Don't reset every time!!! */
/* ol.inner {counter-reset:section;} */

ol.inner li {counter-increment:section;}
ol.inner li:before {content: counters(section,"") ". ";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the `<ol>` inside an unordered list and assign a start position for each:

```
<ul class="main">
  <li>Title Of Section
      <ol>
          <li>Content 1</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Title Of Section
      <ol start="2">
          <li>Content 1</li>
          <li>Content 2</li>
          <li>Content 3</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I put together [a quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/pXGtA/) which uses jquery to automatically update the atart positions of each ordered list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to avoid using javascript. :)